# How do I suppress automatic labeling of figures and tables but still keep references to these objects in my List of Figures and List of Tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, lists

Latex automatically adds numerical labels to the captions of figures and tables. For figures and tables in my Appendix, I have been suppressing these using the caption*{} command, so I can label these objects A1, A2 etc. manually. I would like to keep references to them in the List of Figures and List of Tables however. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and whether you use a command such as `\appendix` at the start of the appendix portion of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you *not* pursue the `\caption*` route for figures and tables in the appendix portion of of your document. As you've discovered, your manual overriding of the standard way of generating captions creates significant follow-up problems elsewhere in the document.

Instead, I would like to suggest that you insert the following four instructions in the document, immediately after `\appendix` (or, depending on your document setup, `\begin{appendices}`):

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection\arabic{table}}
```

The first two instructions reset the `figure` and `table` counters each time a `\section` instruction is encountered. The final two instructions serve to change the way `figure` and `table` numbers are displayed, by prefixing the section-related label ("A", "B", etc). Without the final two instructions, figure and table numbers would be displayed as `A.1`, `B.3`, etc, whereas you've stated that you wish to display them as `A1`, `B3`, etc.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\section{In the beginning, \dots}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{table}  \caption{A table}  \end{table}

\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection\arabic{table}}

\section{Varia}
\begin{figure} \caption{Another figure} \end{figure}
\begin{table}  \caption{Another table}  \end{table}

\section{Miscellanea}
\begin{figure} \caption{A final figure} \end{figure}
\begin{table}  \caption{A final table}  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A follow-up remark: If your document class is `book` rather than `article`, simply replace all instances of `section` with `chapter` in the code shown above.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. Got it working.